# ASP.NET MVC ModelState has error for IEnumeration<SelectListItem> in view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

In an ASP.NET MVC 5 web site, I am populating a drop down in a view and getting the value back in the POST action.  However, ModelState.IsValid is always false.  In investigating why, I found that there is an error for the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property, which contains the data for the drop down.

Here is the exception from the ModelState for the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`property:

> The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' failed because no type converter can convert between these types.

From what I've read, it looks like I am using the view model correctly and setting up the drop down correctly.

- [Asp.net mvc ModelState validity when using dropdownlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992167/asp-net-mvc-modelstate-validity-when-using-dropdownlist)
- https://forums.asp.net/t/1715908.aspx

This is inconvenient because ModelState.IsValid is checked elsewhere for error handling, but in the POST action AvailableStates is irrelevant.  Any ideas as to why the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property always has this error?

I made a simple web site that replicates the issue.

View Model

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SandboxAspNet.Models
{
    public class HomeViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a state.")]
        [Display(Name = "State")]
        public string SelectedState { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailableStates { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SandboxAspNet.Models;

namespace SandboxAspNet.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new HomeViewModel()
            {
                AvailableStates = GetAvailableStates()
            };

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Submit(HomeViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                model.AvailableStates = GetAvailableStates();
                return View("Index", model);
            }

            return View("Success");
        }

        // Generate some dummy data for the drop down
        private static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAvailableStates()
        {
            return new List<SelectListItem>()
            {
                new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = "Alabama",
                    Value = "AL"
                },
                new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = "Alaska",
                    Value = "AK",
                },
                new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = "Arizona",
                    Value = "AZ",
                },
                new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = "Arkanasas",
                    Value = "AR"
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
@model SandboxAspNet.Models.HomeViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Submit", "Home", Model, null))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div>
        <strong>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedState)</strong>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedState, Model.AvailableStates, "--Select a State---", new { @type = "text", @style = "width:100%;", @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedState)
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Just for testing purposes, change the `HomeViewModel model` in your `HttpPost` method with `string theState`

Comment: I did so and while ModelState.IsValid is true, theState is null.  Also, in the production code there are many pieces of data being passed back to the action handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third parameter to `Ajax.BeginForm()` is wrong.  [That parameter is for routeValues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.AjaxHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions%29).

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(
    this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object routeValues,
    AjaxOptions ajaxOptions
)
```

You can possibly just make the third and four parameter `null` if you don't need to do anything more advanced.

`@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Submit", "Home", Model, null))`

Comment: In the production code, off of which this is based, the Model is also passed in as the third parameter.  Sure enough, setting the third parameter to null has fixed it!  Thanks! I will inquire as to why that was done that way originally in the production code.

Comment: It just needs to be `@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Submit", "Home")`